# JAVA heap space error when using Geonetwork metadata full view

Tags: java, postgresql, tomcat, jdbc, geonetwork

I'm using Geonetwork 3.10 with APACHE Tomcat on a CENTOS 7 machine. These are the charatertics of the various components:

- Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.76
- Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.222.b10-0.el7_6.x86_64/jre
- JVM Version:           1.8.0_222-b10
- OS Name:               Linux
- OS Version:            3.10.0-957.27.2.el7.x86_64

My catalog should manage a starting number of metadata of about 35000 files and this number will increase.
Unfortunately, I'm facing the following error when I'm trying to see the full metadata view:

> An error occurred while loading a metadata view

looking at the log using the journalctl -f command it corresponds to the following error:

`DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver] - Resolving exception from handler [public void org.fao.geonet.api.records.formatters.FormatterApi.getRecordFormattedBy(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,org.fao.geonet.api.records.formatters.FormatterWidth,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,org.fao.geonet.api.records.formatters.FormatType,boolean,org.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) throws java.lang.Exception]: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`

Another error still related to Java heap space is the following:

*SEVERE: Unexpected death of background thread containerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space*

that appears looking at

*/var/log/tomcat/catalina.2020-01-24.log*.

I'm using a Postgres database and I have set it in the

```
geonetwork/WEB-INF/config-node/srv.xml
```

file uncommenting the line

```
<import resource="../config-db/postgres-postgis.xml"/>
```

I have set the file `/usr/share/tomcat/bin/setenv.sh` and `/etc/tomcat/tomcat.conf`, respectively, with the following values

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xms3072m -Xmx3072m -XX:PermSize=530m -XX:MaxPermSize=3072m"
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms4096m -Xmx4g -Xss2M -XX:+UseG1GC"
```

The java heap space error also appears during the harvesting

> An error occurred while harvesting a local file:Java heap space.

Another error I use to find in the log is the following

```
*DEBUG [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils] - Could not set JDBC Connection read-only
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Cannot change transaction read-only property in the middle of a transaction.
```

I correctly set the credentials  in the file `geonetwork/WEB-INF/config-db/jdbc.properties`

But it always results in a READ-ONLY connection even if I check the .jdbc.properties I have

```
jdbc.basic.defaultReadOnly=false
```

Could please tell me what I'm doing wrong? Are there any other fine-tunings that I'm not doing?

Comment: I guess you have tried increasing the heap size ... or reducing the number / size of the metadata files?

Comment: @StephenC I already increased the heap size wrt default setting. 
About the size of metadata, it is about 57KB per file I can't reduce it because it contains the information I need. 
The number of metadata can't be reduced because it is a catalog that has to be up to date with the latest available data.

Comment: Maybe you need to increase the heap size some more.  Or perhaps it is something wrong with the way you are using the API (if that is what you are doing ...)  It sounds to me as if Geonetwork is trying to pull all of the metadata into memory at some point.  That doesn't scale.  Are there any other clues, like stacktraces associated with the OOMEs?  Can you share them?

Comment: How can I find these further OOMEs? the log files I was monitoring are already in the post. 
Could you please tell me if I can use other commands to have other logs for this purpose?

Comment: You need to look at the stacktrace for the nested exception.  That should tell you what the code was doing when the OOME occurred, which may give you insights into what needs to be fixed.  Alternatively, just try an even bigger heap.

Comment: As an administrator user open http://localhost:8080/geonetwork/monitor/metrics?pretty=true and check that the memory settings you have set are actually picked by the VM.